# How get extjs-6 sotre's data in mvvm architecture?

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs-mvc, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm developing an [Extjs 6](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic) application using [MVVM architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html). I have a model in `MyApp/model` folder as follow:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'age',   type: 'int'}
    ]
});
```

And my store in `MyApp/store` folder is as follow:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.User',
    data : [
     {firstName: 'Seth',    age: 34},
     {firstName: 'Scott', age: 72},
     {firstName: 'Gary', age: 19},
     {firstName: 'Capybara', age: 208}
    ]
});
```

And the in `Application.js` in `/MyApp` folder add the store as follow:

```
stores: [
    'User'
]
```

now I get store in my application as follow:

```
app = MyApp.getApplication();
users = app.getStore('User');
```

**How can I get store's data**? `users.getData()`? When I user `users.getData()` it returns `[undefined x 4]`. **Where is the problem**? **Is it work correctly**?

Comment: The question is incorrect. MVVM - Model View ViewModel. You don't have a ViewModel. You should define a store in a ViewModel and can get a data over <view>.getViewModel().get(<Stoneware>).getData(). If you just want to iterate over all records you can use method "each" of the store instead of getting data. In any case your question is nothing to do with MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using it correctly. You have to use `users.getData().items` as follow:

`app = MyApp.getApplication();
users = app.getStore('User');
users.getData().items;`